# position menu header with css (divi wordpress theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

i m trying positon my menu header to the left, and i success moving my menu header to the left. But when i saw in mobile, my mobile menu gone missing, please help.
this my code to move menu to the left:

```
#main-header .container.clearfix.et_menu_container{
margin-left: -400px;}
```

Comment: Your theme uses media queries and problem is that your change affected mobile media queries. So, resize window in browser, inspect element(s), and you will find a part of css that you need to change, actually to reset this change for smaller screens.

Comment: well i don't quite understand how to change for mobile device or should i say smaller screen. anyway thk for info @nevermind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the margin-left in mobile, simply add a code like this in your CSS file.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   #main-header .container.clearfix.et_menu_container{
margin-left: initial;}
}
```

The min-width tells when CSS to use the rules below.  In this case, it is when the screen has a maximum of 480 pixels wide. You may have to adjust this settings to get the right look.

The initial reverts back to the default value.  If it doesn't work, then you have to go through the theme css and see what it was set to.

This script should tell your theme to revert back to the theme default if it is in a mobile (small screen).

Answer (score 1):

use percentage value like

```
margin-left: 10%;//write your right percentage
```

it will appear well on all screen sizes